# Rails 7 ActiveStorage fixture attachment isn't attaching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-activestorage

I'm following the documentation at [Active Storage Overview](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures), and trying the answers I've found around here, but no luck.

The assertion in this test always fails:

```
test "verify attached video" do
  att = sponsor_images(:sponsor_video_1).video_att
  assert att.attached?
end
```

Here are my relevant files:

**config/storage.yml**

```
test_fixtures:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage_fixtures") %>
```

**models/sponsor_image.rb**

```
class SponsorImage < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :video_att
  validates :video_att, file_content_type: {
    allow: /^video\/(mp4|m4v)$/,
    if: -> { video_att.attached? }
  }
...
```

**fixtures/sponsor_images.yml**

```
sponsor_video_1:
  sponsor: sponsor_1
  name: Test SponsorImage Video
```

**fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml**

```
video:
  name: video_att
  record: sponsor_image_1 (SponsorImage)
  blob: video_blob
```

**fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml**

```
video_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "1920x1080.mp4", service_name: "test_fixtures" %>
```

The file `fixtures/files/1920x1080.mp4` does exist and is readable.

When I run the test with the debugger, I can see that the attachment exists with the correct data. The file does get created under `tmp/storage_fixtures`. But the `attached?` method returns `false`.

I expect I'm missing something simple, but I sure can't see what it is.

Comment: I've never used minitest, but should the record in your `attachments.yml` be `sponsor_video_1`?

Comment: Yes. Told you it would be something simple. 

Write up an answer (embarassing though it may be) and I'll accept it.

Comment: no worries, you provided great context and the Q&A is bound to help someone else at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `record` identifier in `attachments.yml` needs to be changed from `sponsor_image_1` to `sponsor_video_1` to match the object key name in `sponsor_images.yml`.

It happens to the best of us, that's why testing is important :)

Comment: It does indeed! I've been writing code since my first FORTRAN class in 1979, and I still get bit by these obvious ones sometimes.